# The physical meaning of ${\rm Tr}()$ in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, operators, linear-algebra, trace

I know what trace is in matrix algebra, but does it have any intuitive physical significance when acted on a quantum mechanical operator? What aspect of an operator $A$ does ${\rm Tr}(A)$ capture? Or is it just a convenient mathematical tool and nothing more?

Comment: E.g. is the sum of the eigenvalues.

Comment: "Just a convenient mathematical tool and nothing more"? You might as well ask this about the operator itself. What do you know about the physical meaning of operators?

Comment: Related: [What information does the trace of a matrix give?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137158/2451)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What information does the trace of a matrix give?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137158/)