# Understanding operations with indexes in this example

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

I'm trying to do some exercises about the manipulations of the indexes. I have the tensor $X^{\mu\nu}$ represented by the following matrix
$$[X^{\mu\nu}] = [X] = \begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 & 1 & 0 \\ 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 & 3 & 0 \end{pmatrix}$$

I have to calculate $X^{\mu}_{\phantom{a}\nu}$ so I understodood that

$$X^{\mu}_{\phantom{a}\nu}= X^{\mu\sigma}\eta_{\sigma\nu} = \sum_{k=0}^3 X^{\mu k}\eta_{k \nu}$$

The above object if expanded reads

$$X^{\mu 0}\eta_{0 \nu} + X^{\mu 1} \eta_{1 \nu} + \ldots$$

But the metric tensor $\eta_{\mu \nu} = diag(1, -1, -1, -1)$ has nonzero components only on the diagonal, hence I'd get

$$X^{\mu 0} \eta_{00} + \ldots $$

hence

$$X^{\mu 0} - X^{\mu 1} - X^{\mu 2} - X^{\mu 3}$$

The notation now makes me rather confused because $X^{\mu 0}$ is what? An object from $X^{\mu \nu}$ where the components $\mu$ are the first term of each row, since the column is the $0$-th one and reains fixed, that is

$$X^{\mu 0} = \begin{pmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \\ 0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}$$

If this holds for the other objects too, then what I am doing is summing four $4\times 1$ matrices, and I would get a $4\times 1$ matrix, not a $4\times 4 $ matrix in the end.

I am not understanding this...

Comment: Just write it as a matrix product. The product of two 4-by-4 matrices is still a 4-by-4 matrix even when one of them is diagonal.

Comment: @mikestone Matrix product would be easier, but I wanted to understand why this way does not lear me to the same result. Also, matrix product confuses me, since I would repeat the same for $X_{\mu}^{\phantom{a}\nu}$ but it would be wrong as I understood...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The above object if expanded reads
>
> $$X^{\mu}_{\nu} =X^{\mu 0}\eta_{0 \nu} + X^{\mu 1} \eta_{1 \nu} + \ldots$$

Up to here we are fine because notice we started with a rank 2 tensor (2 free indices) on the left and we still have the same 2 free indices on the right. The next step,

> $$X^{\mu 0} \eta_{00} + \ldots $$

is unwarranted because you lose a free index. **This is no longer equal to the line above.**

If you were summing over $\nu$ then you would be right to drop all the terms that had any non-diagonal elements of $\eta$ as you noted. For instance consider if we contract $\nu$ with some rank 1 tensor $Y$:

$$Y^{\nu}X^{\mu}_{\nu} =Y^{\nu}X^{\mu 0}\eta_{0 \nu} + Y^{\nu}X^{\mu 1} \eta_{1 \nu} + \ldots $$

$$Y^{\nu}X^{\mu}_{\nu} =Y^{0}X^{\mu 0}\eta_{0 0} + Y^{1}X^{\mu 1} \eta_{1 1} + \ldots $$
which would now be a rank one tensor. Note how I indeed dropped terms that had $\eta_{01}$ like you wanted. In summary, never drop a free index, always have the same free indices on the left and the right.

Comment: yeah the assertion that $X^{\mu 0}\eta_{00}$ can be represented by a $4\times 1$ matrix is correct. What is not correct is that $X^{\mu\nu}$ can be written $X^{\mu 0}\eta_{00}+\ldots$

Comment: Oh I got it now (sorry I deleted my comment because I realised I understood). If I leave it written in the good form, as you said, then it becomes the product between $4\times 1$ and $1\times 4$ matrices ($X$ and $\eta$), and it gives a $4\times 4$ matrix. Summing them all gives me what I want! Thank you!

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but I was wondering: how could I compute the trace of $X^{\mu \nu}$? I computed the trace of the "mixed indexes" tensors (the ones with up and down index) and it's zero, and it's ok (I made the calculations. Yet the trace of $X^{\mu \nu}$ is $4$, but can I get it with the metric tensor? I am not able to do it

Comment: Trace is $\eta_{\mu\nu}X^{\mu\nu} = X^\mu_\mu$. Related : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/664659/what-is-the-significance-of-the-trace-of-a-tensor. Its supposed to be $0$ because of the metric.

Comment: Yes, I calculated it. But it gives me zero, whereas the trace of $X^{\mu \nu}$ here is $4$. I guess I did something wrong?