# The significance of trace of a matrix

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, linear-algebra, trace

Since the determinant and trace of a matrix give information about the solution of the 1D propagation system, i.e. the solution is propagating, scattering or tunneling, etc.

How do we extract information from the determinant and trace of a matrix about the solution of propagation (propagating state)?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/137158/2451